# gradle test phases?

Tags: testing, groovy, junit, gradle

Is there a way to build custom test phases in gradle?

I have a series of tests, namely

```
/unit
/local
/remote
```

which is running JUnit managed tests for a couple different purposes. I'd love to be able to run these as test phases, such as `gradle test:unit`, or something like that. Ideally, I could also specify a description for each test phase, so `gradle tasks` describes the role of each of the tests.

Is this possible? If so, how?

I tried this:

```
sourceSets {
    unit {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/groovy/local')
        resources.srcDir file('src/local/resources')
    }
}
dependencies {...}
task unitTest(type: Test){
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.local.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.local.runtimeClasspath
}
```

...as copied from `withIntegrationTests` in the provided samples, but when I run `gradle unitTest`, no tests run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add three `Test` tasks (`testUnit`, `testLocal`, `testRemote`) and configure them accordingly. (Instead of introducing `testUnit`, you could also reuse the `test` task that comes with the Java plugin.) If the sources are in different source folders, it also makes sense to add additional source sets. For the details, have a look at `samples/java/withIntegrationTests` in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: I tried to copy this example to no avail. I've updated my question with what I tried.

Comment: Please always state the Gradle version. If no tests run, it usually means that Gradle couldn't find any test classes. Can you check that build/classes/unit indeed contains class files of JUnit tests?